# Static background needs to be dynamic

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, slider, flexslider

I want my background to move like a slider, because, right now, my background is not moving. Here’s the code I tried to put the shortcode for slider but it’s not working.

```
<div class="SFOI clearfix" style="background: url('') no-repeat top center; background-size: cover; ">
```

I want the background to move:

[image: I want the background to move]

Answer (score 0):

This can use this

**HTML**

```
<div id="slider">
<figure>
 <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/KXdUNp_9oHs/hqdefault.jpg" alt>
 <img src="http://zoedouceur.z.o.pic.centerblog.net/11042612345122694.jpg" alt>
 <img src="http://www.lanu.de/media/thumbnails/867/9c9ca240b73a8f5cf7cbbd8b16473867/df2a2872.jpg" alt>
 <img src="http://strapya.typepad.com/photos/uncategorized/waterfall.jpg" alt>
 <img src="https://naturesimage.files.wordpress.com/2013/06/binnaburra.jpg" alt>
 </figure>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
@keyframes slidy {
  0% { left: 0%; }
  20% { left: 0%; }
  25% { left: -100%; }
  45% { left: -100%; }
  50% { left: -200%; }
  70% { left: -200%; }
  75% { left: -300%; }
  95% { left: -300%; }
  100% { left: -400%; }
  }

body { margin: 0; } 
div#slider { overflow: hidden; }
div#slider figure img { width: 20%; float: left; }
div#slider figure { 
  position: relative;
  width: 500%;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 0;
  animation: 30s slidy infinite; 
  }
```

See this running  [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ponnarasu/t9fbuy0t/)

Comment: Hi Thankyou for your answer! this is wordpress. how can i put multiple slides.

Comment: http://preview.themeforest.net/item/real-estate-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/15486090 here is the exact sample that i want, i cannot create the slider background for my advance search please check the screenshot :(( i badly need help